# react-native-image-picker duration of video

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-video, react-native-image-picker

I'm using `react-native-image-picker` library for video recording and `react-native-video` to play video in which duration of video in `onLoad` callback function is given but how can I use it in my code can anyone please guide me? I have written `durationLimit` in function but it is not working. How can I record video of duration 30 seconds? I tried [this](https://github.com/Saad-Bashar/Find-Video-Length-React-Native)
too but failed.

**My Code**

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';   
import Video from 'react-native-video';

constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      video: '',
      isVideo: true
   };
};
_handleVideoUpload = () => {
   const options = {
      mediaType: 'video',
      videoQuality: 'medium',
      durationLimit: 30000,
      thumbnail: true,
      allowsEditing: true,
   };

   ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (response) => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        // console.warn('User cancelled video picker');
        return true;
      } else if (response.error) {
         // console.warn('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
          console.warn('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
         this.setState({video: response.uri});
      } 
   });
 }

render() {
   return(
     <View>
     {
      this.state.video != '' ?
         <View>                     
           <Video
              ref={ref => this._video = ref}
              source={{ uri: this.state.video }}
              resizeMode={'cover'}
              repeat={true}
              paused = {true}
              onLoad={() => { this._video.seek(2);}} 
           />
       </View>
     : 
       <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={() => this._handleVideoUpload()}
       >
         <Text>Upload Video</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    }
   </View>
);}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey @Riddhi, If you have found any solution please provide here so we can also code in that way.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't found any solution yet @Purvik Rana If I will I definitely post here.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to record a video of 30 seconds you need tu put `30` in `durationLimit`, not `30000`

```
`const options = {
   mediaType: 'video',
   videoQuality: 'medium',
   durationLimit: 30,
   thumbnail: true,
   allowsEditing: true,
};`
```

If you want to know the duration time if video on `<Video />` you can do that:

```
`_onLoad(data){
    let durationVideo = data.duration
}
...
<Video
   ref={ref => this._video = ref}
   source={{ uri: this.state.video }}
   resizeMode={'cover'}
   repeat={true}
   paused = {true}
   onLoad={() => this._onLoad()}
/>`
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: thank you for your help @josecasrillo I tried this but it doesn't work